# Longest known live version of Dazed and Confused?

Tags: concert, led-zeppelin

At worst this is a finite list, but does anyone know how long the longest known live version of Dazed and Confused ran, and from which date?  There are a heck of a lot of bootlegs out there to cull the info from, but I'm trying to track down the mother of all versions.  I know this song ran in excess of a half hour during the 1975 tour.

Comment: It used to be the midnight movie in Tulsa Oklahoma for a while back in the late 70s I will never forget it I love you all.!!!!! I believe LSD 25 was the trip lol God bless you all and keep you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Led Zeppelin's concert in Inglewood, California on March 27, 1975 included the longest version of **Dazed and Confused** the band ever played. On this particular night, they performed an unfathomable 45 minute long version of a song that lasted just 6 minutes and 28 seconds on their official debut release.

The only known document of this mammoth take on the [Jake Holmes classic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dazed_and_Confused_(song)) (contrary to popular belief, Led Zeppelin did *not* write it) is from an audience recording from reknowned California taper Mike Millard, who used professional equipment hidden in a wheelchair to obtain some of the highest-quality audience recordings of the 70's.

Comment: Listen to the original from [*The Above Ground Sound of Jake Holmes*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pTsvs-pAGDc).

Comment: There's also a second source (Hedrick).

Comment: Can you meet me in chat.?  I have a weird thing that happened after the exchange on my question and I want to share it with you.  You can validate the insanity if you want.

Comment: @Citizen - Unfortunately my company computer blocks chat, and I probably won't be around after work.  Heading out for drinks after a tough week.  :o)